# Quicksort visualization?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, visualization, quicksort

I'm fairly new to programming and would like some visual representation of the quicksort algorithm using median-of-three partitioning and a cutoff of 3.

I would like to see the entire iterative process because the Java algorithm is tough to understand for me.

For example, try applying quicksort to this array: [2, 6, 3, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 8]

With the median-of-three rule, the pivot is the median of the leftmost, center, and rightmost elements. So the median of 2, 6, and 8 is 6. What now?

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1582075

Comment: Take a look at the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) pseudo code, it is quite accurate on how to implement the quicksort

Comment: Rouby, how are a bunch of lines being sorted so quickly going to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The next step is partitioning: when you have selected a pivot, move all elements smaller than the pivot to the left and all elements larger to the right. Once this is done, you can separately sort on the left and on the right.

Before partitioning:

```
[2,6,3,1,6,5,2,4,8]
```

After partitioning `<6` on the left, `>=6` on the right:

```
[2,3,1,5,2,4] [6,6,8]
```

To sort left and right, repeat the same procedure on both sides.

I let you discover the very details of the partitioning procedure (the true one leaves the elements in a different order).

Issues to remember:

- after partitioning, there must remain at least one element in either side, otherwise the procedure can loop forever (at worse, the only element left can be the pivot);
- ideally, the partitioning splits the array in two subarrays of roughly equal size; but very unequal sizes can also arise, making the algorithm much slower; the median-of-three heuristic does not fully avoid that phenomenon;
- the algorithm is written in a recursive way (the sorting function calls itself). When sorting the two subarrays, begin with the smallest so that the number of nested calls is minimized. This is important;
- the procedure is overkill for small arrays, this is why it is advisable to switch to a simpler method, like StraightInsertion or StraightSelection in this case.

You can sketch the whole sorting process as a binary tree where a node holds an array, with the pivot distinguished, and has two sons holding the subarrays.

[image]

Comment: Your answer made the most sense to me. Let me know if I'm interpreting it correctly. You pick a median. Sort numbers less than median to left and greater than median to right. Then you split the left and right and do the same process by picking a median and sorting to left to right. Once both are finished you merge them together with the original median. Is this correct? This interpretation seems to work so I'm not sure.

Comment: To be precise, you don't "sort" the numbers left & right, you partition them left & right (meaning that the order doesn't matter); after partitioning, you sort both subarrays; the "merge" is a no-op as the elements are already at the right place; and the pivot element is not handled specially: it just belongs to one of the subarrays.

Comment: So I'm trying to sort this: {3,1,4,1,5,9,2,6,5,3,5}. Median is 5. {3,1,4,1,2,3|5|5,9,6,5}. For {3,1,4,1,2,3} median is 3, so using the same left and right method it turns into {1,1,2,3,3,4}. For {5,9,6,5} median is 5, but it transformed into an unsorted subarray: {5,5,9,6}. What went wrong? Also in your visual, does it traverse to make sure it is sorted? How does it know whether the subarray is sorted or not? Checking it is sorted or else doing another quick sort makes it a little inefficient.

Comment: Check it step by step by hand. During debugging you can also add a check for the partition condition.

Comment: What do you mean by step by step exactly?

Comment: Simulate the program.

Answer (score 2):

> So the medium of 2,6,8 is 6. What now?

The next step is to partition the array into the left half, containing elements that are less than 6, and the right half, containing elements that are equal to or greater than 6. Then we call quicksort on each half.

The following Java program implements quicksort, displaying each subarray before and after sorting. It also displays the choice of median.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Quicksort {
  void swap(int[] data, int i, int j) {
    int t = data[i];
    data[i] = data[j];
    data[j] = t;
  }

  void display(int[] data, int left, int right) {
    for (int i = 0; i < right; ++i) {
      System.out.print(i < left ? "  " : " "+data[i]);
    }
    System.out.println();
  }

  //--- in-place implementation with median-of-three pivot
  int quicksort(int[] data, int left, int right, int callId) {
    int saveCallId = callId;
    System.out.print(callId+". sorting:");
    display(data, left, right);
    if (left+1 >= right) {
      System.out.print("  "+saveCallId+". result:");
      display(data, left, right);
      return callId;
    }
    int ai = left, bi = (left+right)/2, ci = right-1, pos;
    int a = data[ai], b = data[bi], c = data[ci];
    if (a < b) {
      if (c < a) {
        pos = ai;
      } else if (c < b) {
        pos = ci;
      } else {
        pos = bi;
      }
    } else {
      if (c < b) {
        pos = bi;
      } else if (c < a) {
        pos = ci;
      } else {
        pos = ai;
      }
    }
    int pivot = data[pos];
    System.out.println("   median of ["+a+", "+b+", "+c+"] is "+pivot);
    swap(data, right-1, pos);
    int tail = left;
    for (int i = left; i != right-1; ++i) {
      if (data[i] < pivot) {
        swap(data, tail, i);
        ++tail;
      }
    }
    swap(data, right-1, tail);
    callId = quicksort(data, left, tail, ++callId);
    callId = quicksort(data, tail+1, right, ++callId);
    System.out.print("  "+saveCallId+". result:");
    display(data, left, right);
    return callId;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] data = new int[]{ 2, 6, 3, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 8 };
    new Quicksort().quicksort(data, 0, data.length, 0);
  }
}
```

For the input case `{ 2, 6, 3, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 8 }`, the output is:

```
0. sorting: 2 6 3 1 6 5 2 4 8
   median of [2, 6, 8] is 6
1. sorting: 2 3 1 5 2 4
   median of [2, 5, 4] is 4
2. sorting: 2 3 1 2
   median of [2, 1, 2] is 2
3. sorting: 1
  3. result: 1
4. sorting:     2 3
   median of [2, 3, 3] is 3
5. sorting:     2
  5. result:     2
6. sorting:        
  6. result:        
  4. result:     2 3
  2. result: 1 2 2 3
7. sorting:           5
  7. result:           5
  1. result: 1 2 2 3 4 5
8. sorting:               6 8
   median of [6, 8, 8] is 8
9. sorting:               6
  9. result:               6
10. sorting:                  
  10. result:                  
  8. result:               6 8
  0. result: 1 2 2 3 4 5 6 6 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see an interactive visualization and play with it at [the walnut](https://thewalnut.io/visualizer/visualize/3474/334/). It uses the Dijkstra partitioning (smaller, equal, larger than the pivot).